# Do I need Threading Python Computer Vison

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, pyautogui

Do I need threading?  I figured I could just write an entire separate python file and run concurrently but didn't seem very elegant.

Example of Code

```
while (True):
    cap screen
    process screen

    if standard deviation > Threasholdstd:   
      do something

    if movement not detected after 20 seconds
       do something
       start monitoring for Standard deviation again
```

Not sure if there is some way to accomplish this. Thanks guys!

Comment: It depends on what you want to do, and where your bottleneck is, if you have one. You’ll need a lot more detail in your question, with a clear indication of what problem you are facing, to get a good answer. If you’re not really facing a problem, and you are wondering about this before implementing anything, then the right answer is even more difficult to predict. :)

Comment: I have a working object movement detection, along with take action upon movement.  I just have not been able to figure out how to handle if it does not detect movement within a certain time frame. Eg. x seconds than I want it to perform and action than continue with object movement detection.  Problem I run into is any if loops else loops etc that I put a time.sleep() into the program freezes.

Comment: I presume you "cap screen" periodically, probably many times per second. So, even though you don't detect movement, the loop is still running, and you can compare current time with last time you detected something, and if the difference is > 20 seconds then "do something". No need for threads there.

Comment: Not sure how to give you credit for answer Dan but this works.  Thanks!

Comment: No worries, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I presume you "cap screen" periodically, probably many times per second. So, even though you don't detect movement, the loop is still running, and you can compare current time with last time you detected something, and if the difference is > 20 seconds then "do something". No need for threads there. – Dan Mašek